# What is the proper way of updating subscriptions to the Glass timline when the IP of the target host changes?

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

Here's a situation that occurred to my team:

- we inserted a Mirror API subscription with a CallbackUrl under a domain we control (the corresponding A record pointed to, say, IP1)
- we verified we could receive Mirror API notifications from Glass devices
- we changed the A record of our domain to point to a new host with a different IP address (let's call it IP2).
- even after propagation of the updated A record, the Mirror API kept sending the notification to IP1 rather than IP2

Is the IP of the host associated with the callback URL cached by the Mirror API ?

Then, we tried the following:

- we deleted the subscription and created a new one. The notifications kept going to IP1
- we uninstalled and re-installed the Glassware, did a new Oauth authorization, etc.
  We verified that on listing the active subscriptions,
  they looked "fresh", with a recent "updated" timestamp.
  However, notifications are go to the old IP address IP1.

Any ideas on what may be going on, and how to overcome this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Also submitted to issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=36&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary

Comment: How long has it been? What was the TTL on the domain name before you started?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The TTL was set to 12 hours and, yes, we didn't wait for that long. After 3-4 hours the new A record was visible by geographically disperse collaborators and we assumed it was safe to go. We'll try again.